# Something wrong with splinefun()

Tags: r, curve-fitting, spline, derivative

Something wrong in my code. I want to obtain the function e(p) = p * L'(p) / L(p) using some fitting technique.

For instance, if L(p) = p^4, then e(p)=4, but when I try to do this using splinefun(), something wrong hapens:

```
p <- 1:50/50
lp <- p^4

spl <- splinefun(p,lp)
dlp <- spl(p, deriv = 1)
p*dlp/lp
```

and the result

```
[1] 9.464102 3.816987 4.014530 3.998358 4.000225 3.999965 4.000006 3.999999
[9] 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000
[17] 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000
[25] 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000
[33] 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000
[41] 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.000001 3.999996
[49] 4.000012 3.999956 `
```

Why do the numbers 9.464102 3.816987 appear? Is it possible to obtain 4 in all the cases?

Comment: i think you're just dealing with small-number roundoff and spline (and mechanical derivative) approximations.  Try plotting `lp` ,`dlp`, and the output of `spl(p,0)` and you'll see things look reasonable.

Comment: Hi Carl! Well, the results have not changed with spl(p,0)...and yes it is something related to small-number because using L(p)=p^6 the results get worse.

Comment: It's not "something."  That's the way splines, and computers, work.  Try not worrying so much about small numbers (which cause big problems when they're in the denominator) and/or taking the log of everything.

Comment: With log the issue persists, i.e. using log(p) + log(dlp) - log(lp). So, in this case, how demonstrate that p*dlp/lp is constant?